# orderby menu_order show max 10 pages

Tags: php, wordpress

trying to put together a wp site for a martial arts centre, and they need a list of their instructors.
i try to get all the children of the instructor page appear in list by their page order, and that works fine, except it only shows the first 10 pages, and there is currently 13 instructor pages...

this is the code i used:

```
        <section id="instruktorer">
            <div class="indent">
                <?php 
                $query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=instruktorer' );
                $services_id = $query->queried_object->ID;


                /* Restore original Post Data */
                wp_reset_postdata();

                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'post_parent' => $services_id,
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                );
                $services_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                // The Loop
                if ( $services_query->have_posts() ) {

                echo '<ul class="instruktorer">';
                while ( $services_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $services_query->the_post();
                    echo '<li class="clear">';
                    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" figure class="instruktorer-thumb">';
                    the_post_thumbnail('instructor-pic');
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '</figure>'; 
                    echo '<div class="caption">' . get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() )->post_excerpt . '</div>';
                    echo '</li>';
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                }

                /* Restore original Post Data */
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
        </div><!-- .indent -->
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to this:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent' => $services_id,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```